# very quick ip-as-int lookup for IPv4 socket under linux x86_64?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

linux x86_64, gcc, ipv4.

here is how I understand finding out who my IPv4 client is.  first, I start with a client handle, that is not a pointer but an integer (huh?).  then, I need to allocate space for a destination sockaddr structure, and allocate space for an unsigned int to hold its length (passed as a reference).  then I call getsockname() with the integer client handle and my destination sockaddress and sockaddress length.  (internally, presumably getsockname() copies the kernel's IP representation and other info into my own sockaddr.)  then I need to call ntoa() with the sockaddr structure to get a string.  and finally, I need to convert this string into an integer.  (there is also both getpeername and getsockname.)

these are the examples that I have seen.  this seems portable but inefficient for a server where latency is important.  but let's say I want to stay inside linux on the x86_64 architecture and IPv4.  I would guess that the kernel internals already store an IP number as an int somewhere, so that most roundtrip calls here are not necessary, so that the IPv4 could be looked up directly and a lot faster without intermediate storage.  does such a function exist?  I looked for a long time, but could not find it.

it would make a lot of sense if the getsockname() function had an alternative that simply returned an IP representation as a single integer.  this would also save the time and overhead of having to make a copy.  does this exist?  (PS: incidentally, if it did exist, it would be logical to have an ntoa()-like call that mapped this unique-per-IP int to the standard xx.xx.xx.xx string, i.e., obviating the need for the intermediate sockaddress.)

if such a function does not exist, at the very least, I should be able to avoid the ntoa to string and back to integer conversion.  this means I would have to know which (or even whether) of the bytes in the sockaddr structure represent the IP, so I could cast these bytes into a 4-byte C integer.  I think this is bytes 2-6.  right?

/iaw

Comment: Have you benchmarked it to see if it's actually a problem? Latency on most networks is measured in milliseconds, versus nanoseconds for memory access and typical ALU operations.

Comment: thank you, thomas.  nope, not yet.  you are probably right that it's worrying about nothing too important here, though I will want to handle thousands of clients and will call this many many times.  but its more than only speed.  Such code would be less portable, but more parsimonious and use less memory management, too.  (well, I could encapsulate the current calling sequence to look like what I want.)  I am asking the question "does this already exist and I just don't know the right function name, or does this really have to be this complex for this simple a task?" novice=incredulous

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to parse your question - I might be getting some of the details wrong.

"*client handle, that is not a pointer but an integer*"

- Actually its a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

"*allocate space for a destination sockaddr structure, and allocate space for an unsigned int to hold its length*"

- Yes, these do need to be allocated, but it doesn't matter where from.  Allocating from the stack would certainly be faster than allocating from the heap (malloc() and friends)

"*I call getsockname() with the integer client handle and my destination sockaddress and sockaddress length*"

I'm not sure if you're after the local or the remote address for a given socket:

- [getsockname()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/getsockname.html) will give you the local address.
- [getpeername()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/getpeername.html) will give you the remote address.

Regardless, I don't see any need for any ntoa()-like call if all you need is the `int` representation of the IP address - the `struct sockaddr_in` filled in by the get[peer|sock]name() call already contains that in the [`sin_addr` member](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html).

So assuming you already have the client FD (returned from `accept()`) and you want the remote address for that socket then all you need to do is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

...

    struct sockaddr_in peer_sa;                         // Stack allocation
    socklen_t peer_sa_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // Stack allocation
    int fd;
    int status;

...

    // fd is the client file descriptor, as returned by accept()
    status = getpeername(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_sa, &peer_sa_len);
    // check your return codes!

    printf("peer address %s as int is %d\n",
       inet_ntoa(peer_sa.sin_addr), peer_sa.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

Note `inet_ntoa(peer_sa.sin_addr)` is just used above for illustrative purposes.

Also note this is ***very IPv4*** specific.  If you expect IPv6 clients too, then you'll need to use `struct sockaddr_storage` instead (which should be sized big enough to fit any address family).  Also 128bit IPv6 addresses obviuosly don't fit into 32bit integers.  Also you would have to use [inet_ntop()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/inet_ntop.html) to give a text representation of the address.

Comment: `sockaddr_in6` is specific to IPv6. To support both IPv4 and IPv6 (or any `sockaddr`-based protocol) in a more agnostic way, use `sockaddr_storage` instead.

Comment: thanks.  this is what I needed.  I thought it was an int from http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket .  I am learning from extending code Donahoo&Calvert.  D&C is a nice start.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - absolutely correct - thanks for catching this - I'll update the answer

Comment: @ivoWelch - FDs are, as far as I know, always stored in ints.  The point is they are *definitely not* pointers.  There is is socket structure in the kernel, but a pointer to that structure would make no sense in userspace.

Comment: opinion---this is really an arcane programming interface, given that I am learning it for the first time, I wonder why there is not a file-mimicking easier standard interface atop these base functions.  tcpserver( portnum, &listener ), and listener just reads stdin and writes stdout.  it should inquire with an fstat-like call on the file handle.  this should be simpler.

Comment: @ivoWelch - You're entitled to your opinion ;-).  But I suspect there are quite a few that would disagree with you.  The [Berkeley Socket interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) is certainly not particularly modern.  While originally part of BSD unix, its semantics have been reproduced in just about every major OS there is out there.  It really has stood the test of time with very few revisions.  While the degenerate cases of creating simple TCP clients and servers may seem somewhat verbose with this interface, the interface is capable of much more because of its flexibility.

Comment: agreed.  it's not that I think it should be replaced.  it's that I think there should be an easier interface for the plain-vanilla, perhaps built on top of it.  sort of like inetd, but inside C.

Comment: @ivoWelch - I searched google for "c tcp client server library".  Something which might be of interest to you is this result for [libmsock](http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/libmsock/libmsock.html)

Comment: wow---I looked for something like libmsock for a long time.  I wish this had be more prominent and I would have found it.  it would have saved me a few days...thanks from me and anyone else reading this thread in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The `sockaddr_in` structure filled out by `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` for an IPv4 connection *is* the internal binary representation of the socket address.

If you have a pointer `struct sockaddr_in *sin` that points at a filled out `sockaddr_in`, then `sin->sin_addr.s_addr` is a `uint32_t` that represents the IPv4 address in network byte order.

Note that `getsockname()` retrieves the address of the local side of the connection, and `getpeername()` the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: I am a beginner at this stuff.)

OK, I think I have the code cleanly worked out now.  84 lines.  The code is *not* portable.  It is only supposed to work with IPv4 if the server is a linux x86_64.  it should compile with gcc and run cleanly out of the box.

the following starts a TCP server that accepts a single client.  The server has its integer handle servSock, the client has its integer handle clntSock.  The code contains the functions that take as input only these integer handles, and return the server and client IP addresses, either in unique integer form (eg iwhoareyou) or in string form (eg swhoareyou).

I believe this code is behaving nicely, including executing all appropriate clean-up code.  (It does not timeout, but this is not important because it closes the connection immediately after a client appears.  no recv or send.)  sometimes, it returns 0.0.0.0, sometimes it returns 127.0.0.1, but I believe this is normal behavior.

If there is still a bug, even a mild one, please let me know.  due paranoia when dealing with networks and many processes...

```
#include <stdio.h>      // printf, fprintf
#include <sys/socket.h> // socket, bind, connect
#include <arpa/inet.h>  // sockaddr_in, inet_ntoa
#include <stdlib.h>     // exit
#include <string.h>     // strcpy, bzero
#include <unistd.h>     // close

/****************************************************************/
#define IPNAMELEN 32
typedef char IPNAME[IPNAMELEN];  // must fit 4*4 + terminator

/****************************************************************/

static inline unsigned long iwho( const int clntSocket,
              int (*function)(const int, struct sockaddr *, unsigned int *) ) {
  struct sockaddr_in ipsock_in;
  unsigned int cisl= sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
  if (getpeername( clntSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&ipsock_in, &cisl )) return 0;
  return  *((unsigned long *) (&ipsock_in.sin_addr));
}

static inline unsigned long iwhoareyou( const int clntSocket ) {
    return iwho(clntSocket, getpeername ); }

static inline char *swhoareyou( const int clntSocket, IPNAME ipbuf ) {
  unsigned long il= iwhoareyou(clntSocket);
  return strcpy(ipbuf, inet_ntoa( *((struct in_addr *) (&il)) ));
}


static inline unsigned long iwhoami( const int servSocket ) {
     return iwho(servSocket, getsockname ); }

static inline char *swhoami( const int servSocket, IPNAME ipbuf ) {
  unsigned long il= iwhoareyou(servSocket);
  return strcpy(ipbuf, inet_ntoa( *((struct in_addr *) (&il)) ));
}


/****************************************************************/
int main() {
  const unsigned short ServPort=8081;

  void die(char *s) { fputs(s, stderr); fputc('\n', stderr); exit(1); }

  int servSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (servSock<=0) die("cannot socket()");

  struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;
  bzero( &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));
  ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  ServAddr.sin_port = htons(ServPort);

  {
    int yes=1;    // tell the OS that we want to use it again
    if (setsockopt(servSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) == -1) die("cannot setsockopt");
  }

  if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr)) < 0) die("cannot bind");

  if (listen(servSock, 2) < 0) die("cannot listen");

  struct sockaddr_in ClntAddr;
  unsigned int clntLen = sizeof(ClntAddr);
  int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr, &clntLen);
  if (clntSock < 0) die("cannot accept()");

  printf("Server= %s.\n", inet_ntoa(ServAddr.sin_addr));
  printf("Client= %s.\n", inet_ntoa(ClntAddr.sin_addr));

  IPNAME buf;
  printf("Via Function on clntSock: '%lu' and '%s'\n", iwhoareyou(clntSock), swhoareyou(clntSock, buf));
  printf("Via Function on servSock: '%lu' and '%s'\n", iwhoami(servSock), swhoami(servSock, buf));

  if (close(clntSock)) die("cannot close clnt");
  if (close(servSock)) die("cannot close serv");

  printf("Happy Ending\n");
  return 0;
}
```